# Issue with TFS adding extra overhead to files when building

Tags: tfs, build-definition

My TFS build definition have started to add some extra overhead(Probably windows line endings) to some of the files that are included in my project. Any ideas as how to avoid this?

The files are used to update a linux machine that my application connects to. When I check in the file it is 1001 bytes in size and if i download it from TFS/git it is also 1001 bytes in size. After it is included in the build and installed the size of the file is now 1022 bytes in size.

If I build the project locally and installed it from there the size of the file is 1001 bytes.

We are running version 2017 (15.117.26714.0(Tfs2017.Update2))

It has worked in the past. Not sure if the TFS was updated or maybe the agent was changed.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Best regards

Kasper

Comment: Can you share some more details such as an example file, how you build the code and what you do on deployment?

Comment: Also you can try comparing the files with compare tool to check the changes between the normal and the 1022 bytes one, then share the info for further troubleshoot.

Comment: I have run the two files through WinMerge. The original file uses Unix carriage return. After building on TFS and installing the resulting msi the file now has windows carriage return.
One of the files is a simple linux inittab file.

Comment: It looks like it happens in the Get sources step in the build process. The change is performed when the files are copied from the remote repository into the local repository. 
When I check the files in the local respository the carriage return has been changed.